# What does "error: assignment to expression with array type" mean?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I try to compile the following code, but I constantly get this error.

```
    char command[100];
    FILE *fp;
    command = sprintf(command, "sudo asterisk -rx \"pjsip show aor %s\"", row[i]);
    fp = popen (command, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to run command\n" );
        exit(1);
```

This error appears: "error: assignment to expression with array type"

Comment: It means you attempt to assign to an array, which is not possible. And [`sprintf` (and related functions)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) doesn't return a string anyway. And you don't need that. And you should really be using `snprintf` instead.

Comment: because, in the LHS, you're using an array type, which is not assignable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the value of `sprintf()` to a variable which has array type. Arrays are not modifiable lvalues; so you can't assign to them. `sprintf()` returns an `int` -- so you need to assign its value to an `int`. However, I'd suggest to avoid `sprintf()` and use [`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) instead. Because `sprintf()` is prone to buffer overflow.

```
int rc = snprintf(command, sizeof command, "sudo asterisk -rx \"pjsip show aor %s\"", row[i]);
```